# error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Tags: c++

What is the problem in this code I have copied from `layers_id_colors_and_visibility.h`?

```
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
error C2017: illegal escape sequence
error C2017: illegal escape sequence
error C2017: illegal escape sequence
error C2017: illegal escape sequence
error C2017: illegal escape sequence
```

```
#define DECLARE_LAYERS_ORDER_LIST(list) int list[LAYER_COUNT] =\
{   LAYER_N_FRONT,\
    LAYER_N_15, LAYER_N_14, LAYER_N_13, LAYER_N_12,\
    LAYER_N_11, LAYER_N_10, LAYER_N_9, LAYER_N_8,\
    LAYER_N_7, LAYER_N_6, LAYER_N_5, LAYER_N_4,\
    LAYER_N_3, LAYER_N_2,\
    LAYER_N_BACK,\
    ADHESIVE_N_FRONT , ADHESIVE_N_BACK,\
    SOLDERPASTE_N_FRONT, SOLDERPASTE_N_BACK,\
    SILKSCREEN_N_FRONT, SILKSCREEN_N_BACK,\
    SOLDERMASK_N_FRONT, SOLDERMASK_N_BACK,\
    DRAW_N,\
    COMMENT_N,\
    ECO1_N, ECO2_N,\
    EDGE_N,\
    UNUSED_LAYER_29, UNUSED_LAYER_30, UNUSED_LAYER_31\
};
```

Comment: Which compiler gave you this warning message? Was the error thrown _here_ or was it thrown at a _use_ of this macro?

Comment: The C2447 implies Visual Studio.

Comment: You could replace this with a function.

Comment: The illegal escape sequence errors makes me think that there might be whitespace to the right of one or more backslashes.

Comment: Ha i Got it..@WayneTanner .. as you said - white spaces were there..You are awesome man :) Thanks you guys sarnold ,steve Howard, chris

Comment: Not exactly, @Chris. This is a macro that expands to a variable declaration. Functions can't do that. However, since the only input is the name of the declared variable, the macro seems rather pointless and could be replaced with a single array declaration.

Comment: @RobKennedy, my suggestion has an intended use of `int list [LAYER_COUNT] = makeList();` or something like that.

Comment: You might want to remove the `;` at the end of the macro definition, since you'll probably want to add one when you invoke it: `DECLARE_LAYERS_ORDER_LIST(foo);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The illegal escape sequence errors makes me think that there might be white space to the right of one or more backslashes.

Now its solved..

thanks all..